# Azure Websites: How to retrieve the current deployment id?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Before the Azure SDK 2, There was the `RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId` property that would return a string identifying the current deployment. However, this seems to be gone/obsolete in the new SDK.

What's the easiest way to get this id from within the web application?

Comment: it is still available in SDK 2.3 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.deploymentid.aspx

Comment: @viperguynaz So then, which NuGet package do I import?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime is part of the Azure SDK, not a NuGet package.  You need to install the [latest SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).  In the Namespace: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime (Assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime [in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll]) you will find the [RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.deploymentid.aspx).